# How to help the compiler deduce template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this method:

```
template <typename Type>
static QList<Type> comboListToItemsList(QList<QList<QVariant>>& comboList) {
    QList<Type> itemsList;
    if (comboList.length() > 0) {
        foreach (QList<QVariant> dbItem, comboList) {
            Type item(dbItem);
            itemsList.append(item);
        }
    }
    return itemsList;
}
```

and when I call it:

```
QList<SettingItem> settingItems = 
(QList<SettingItem>) DatabaseManager::comboListToItemsList(result.first);
```

it goes "cannot deduce template parameter Type". How can I help the compiler more with figuring it out than how I already did by adding

```
(QList<SettingItem>)
```

? I have enum with names of subclasses the method is created for but don't really know how to make use of it here...

Comment: How you use the result of a function has nothing to do with it. You'll have to explicitly specify the type used in the return value as a template argument.

Comment: @chris so calling it as "combo...List(List list, Type emptyItem)" is only solution? Doesn't look pretty... :(

Comment: What? No, give it an explicit template argument because it can't be deduced from the return type. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify it as a template argument, as @chris said.

```
QList<SettingItem> settingItems = DatabaseManager::comboListToItemsList<SettingItem>(result.first);
```